# jquery ui datepicker range clear value based on another selected value

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker, date-range

I use JQuery UI datepicker range that used in the following article ([jquery ui date range 15 day between two date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42447309/jquery-ui-date-range-15-day-between-two-date)) for my form, it is working perfectly, the issue is I have another drop-down list column, I want to clear 1 of the date column when I select a value from the drop-down list.
below is the code I'm using from the article:

```js
$(function () {
    $("#txtFrom").datepicker({      
       onSelect: function(selectedDate) {
            //$("#cal4").datepicker("setDate", selectedDate);
            var date = $(this).datepicker("getDate"); 
            date.setDate(date.getDate() + 15);
            $("#txtTo").datepicker("setDate", date);
            $("#txtTo").datepicker("option", "minDate", selectedDate);
            $("#txtTo").datepicker("option", "maxDate", date);
        }
    });
    
    
  $("#txtTo").datepicker({
   changeMonth: true,
   changeYear: true
  })  
    
});
```

```html
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<input type="text" id="txtFrom" />

<input type="text" id="txtTo" />
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I do not see this Select drop-down in your example. Please provide a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1):

Something like this? trigger event on change

```
  $("#txtTo").datepicker({
   changeMonth: true,
   changeYear: true
  }).on( "change", function() {
   //add your code ref: txtFrom
  }),
```

Comment: So, on (on change)  where I should add the drop-down ID. because I need to clear txtTo value. and disable it.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example that might help. I did a three way choice example from a `<select>` element. The choice determines what datepickers are available.

```js
$(function() {
  $("#txtFrom").datepicker({
    onSelect: function(selectedDate) {
      $("#txtTo").datepicker("option", {
        defaultDate: selectedDate,
        minDate: selectedDate,
        maxDate: "+15d"
      });
    }
  });

  $("#txtTo").datepicker({
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true
  });

  $("#slctDate").change(function() {
    switch ($("option:selected", this).val()) {
      case "None":
        $("#txtFrom, #txtTo").val("").prop("disabled", true);
        break;
      case "Single":
        $("#txtFrom, #txtTo").prop("disabled", false);
        $("#txtTo").val("").prop("disabled", true);
        break;
      case "Range":
        $("#txtFrom, #txtTo").prop("disabled", false);
        break;
    }
  });

});
```

```html
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>

Pick Choice:
<select id="slctDate">
  <option></option>
  <option>None</option>
  <option>Single</option>
  <option>Range</option>
</select>
<br />
<input type="text" id="txtFrom" disabled="true" />
<input type="text" id="txtTo" disabled="true" />
```

> **MaxDate**
>
> **String**: A string in the format defined by the dateFormat option, or a relative date. Relative dates must contain value and period pairs; valid periods are `"y"` for years, `"m"` for months, `"w"` for weeks, and `"d"` for days. For example, `"+1m +7d"` represents one month and seven days from today.

From: http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/ - Packed full of help.

A bit easier to set the max date this way, slightly less code.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, by adding On Change on txtForm function.